# C# MSChart Axis Height

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

After a quick look in the MSChart code with DotPeek, I didn't find anything.

Does someone know how to get the Axis height in a ChartArea? Like the size used by an Axis in the Position object of the ChartArea.

Exemple:

[image: Exemple]

I want the size (height and width in percent) of the red rectangle of this chart, because every Position and ElementPosition are in percent.

I tried something like this :

```
(100 - MSChart.ChartArea.InnerPlotPosition.Height) * (MSChart.ChartArea.Position.Height / 100)
```

But i have some trouble with the space that MSChart takes up too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the value on the Y axis on a chart you can get the `Maximum` value by looking at the chart area.

You will have to determine your chart area as it can be a collection or char areas.
`chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum`

on this chart it is 30

[image]

and `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum`  is 11.

According to the documentation the [InnerPlot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.innerplotposition?view=netframework-4.8) area is the size of the plotting area.
[image]
in this graph it is `Size: {Width = 88.3745 Height = 80.81133}`

if that doesn't answer your question then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283394/ms-charts-getting-the-real-innerplotposition/7301999) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank for answering, for the Axis X there is a way to get only the height ? Because MSChart takes some space up and down and i dont have the hand on it.

I tried something like MSChart.ChartArea.Position - MSChart.ChartArea.InnerPlotPosition but there is a little gap due to the up space taken by MSChart.

Comment: @Tom Flenner is it posible to update your question with a picture to show what you mean?

Comment: I don't think there is a value that gives that value did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283394/ms-charts-getting-the-real-innerplotposition/7301999) help at all? I think it is something that will have to be calculated.